# Google Maps JS: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addDomListener' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps, dom

I'm getting the "*Cannot call method 'addDomListener' of undefined*" error with the `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` code line, where `event` is 'undefined'. My code below is basically copied from an example on developer.google.com.

```
$(function () {
   var officeMap = $("#map-canvas");
   if (officeMap.length > 0) {
      var map;
      function initialize()  {
         var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644), zoom: 8 
         };
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   }
});
```

The google maps script (with API key) is loaded before this at the end of the document body (using Modernizr), looking like this: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myApiKey&sensor=false" (I switch "myApiKey" with generate key ofc :))

Does the error indicate that the Google Maps script didn't load first? Or is my API-key invalid?
Or something else?

Comment: It could be that api is not loaded because of your key. And you don't need key to make this code running. See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/banom/1/edit).

Comment: Why are you loading the API in the body?  Why not the head of the document? And you are going to have issues if you don't wait for the onload event to fire before initializing the map (although it can be made to work without doing that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google code sample is correct, but not going to run in most website given there is ajax script loading involve. And yes you are right the google script is not loaded at the point when you call the function.

Take a look at the source of that google script, it is not the full javascript sdk, it is just a proxy/starter file. I remember it is not like this last time when those sample code works without problem.

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize"></script>
 <script>

function initialize() {
   var officeMap = $("#map-canvas");
   if (officeMap.length > 0) {
      var map;

         var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644), zoom: 8 
         };
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

   }
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Yes, got it to work with callback function (no error in console). But my map has no content, with 0px height :/  Any idea?

Comment: your div must set width and height in css or style

Comment: It has always been 100% width and height

Comment: you can't use percentage for map. it is not text content browser does not handle the resizing. you need to put a physical size on the div, or try http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead of your key

```
<script type="text/javascript"      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
```

My code

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

        function initialize()
        {
        var mapProp = {
          center:myCenter,
          zoom:8,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maparea'),mapProp);

        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
          position:myCenter,
          title:'Hi'
          });

        marker.setMap(map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content:'',
          boxStyle: {
                  maxHeight:200
                }
          });

        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```